# Custom post type with multiple URLs (1 for each assigned term)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This is how my post archive page looks like:

[image]

Under each term there are belonging posts listed. Some of the posts has more than one term assigned to them and consequently they are appearing multiple times which is exactly what I want.

Now the problem is that I want those posts to have as many URLs as terms and then adjust part of its content depending on URL it was accessed from. For example (see picture above):

Post #6 under "Term 1 title" should have URL like this: http://website.com/term-1-slug/post-6-slug/ and under "Term 2 title": http://website.com/term-2-slug/post-6-slug/

Adjusting the content is not a problem... All I need is to be able to access post through URLs like explained above and then in single-post template retrieve desired term ID to adjust content accordingly.

I'm grateful for any kind of help in advance!